# C Program Help in Upper Casing First Letter of Input

Tags: c

I am a beginner coder and writing a code that

> asks for the user's name
>
> check if the length is >15, if it is, it will ask the user to input a shorter name when they restart the program
>
> if the length is valid, upper case the first letter of the entered name
>
> display something like "Hi *name*"

However, The program keeps exiting no matter what I enter. Here is what I did :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str_name[15];

    printf("Please enter your first name to begin: ");
    scanf_s("%14s", str_name, _countof(str_name));
    getchar();
    
    if (strlen(str_name) > 15)
    {
        printf("The entered name is too long, please restart the program and try again.");
        getchar();
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        str_name[0] = toupper(str_name[0]);

        printf("Hi %s.\n", str_name);
        getchar();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C or C++? Decide one language.

Comment: `scanf_s("%14s",......` instead of `scanf_s("%9s",.....`.

Comment: `char str_name[15];` --> `char str_name[16] = {0};` You must have room for a null terminator, so `15+1` chars

Comment: `printf("Hi %s.\n", Name);` is UB: `Name` is 1 byte and not a c-string

Comment: Why have `char Name[1]`? This array only has one space. You could just use a single `char Name` instead.

Comment: Please correct the indentation!

Comment: Hi Roadrunner, I tried using 'char Name' , but the next line will have an error "expression must have pointer-to-object type"

Comment: @MarkTian The code has changed. simply updated `str_name[0]` should be enough, and what you had before `char Name[1]` should not be needed. Also as I showed in my post, you can just use `fgets()` to read input strings. Using `scanf()` is not the best at this.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  Amongst other things, it is missing the statement: `#include <string.h>`  for the `strlen()`

Comment: why use some 'odd ball' function like: `_countof()`  when the C language has the built in preprocessor operator: `sizeof()`?

Comment: a returned value from main() of 0  is indicating SUCCESS.  Suggest 1) use the values defined in stdlib.h of : `EXIT_FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS`.  Where, in this case, the appropriate value would be `EXIT_FAILURE`.

Comment: the function: `scanf_s()` is a windows only function, I.E. not portable.  Suggest using something like: `scanf("%14s", str_name);`  Also, when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this line: `if (strlen(str_name) > 15)` is not correct.   1) the input field is only 15 characters and every string needs the NUL terminator byte.  2) `strlen()` returns the index to the NUL byte and `index`s in C start with 0, not 1.

Comment: the posted code contains 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis (and using them makes the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.)   In this case, the number14 and the number 15.  suggest: ... `#define MAX_NAME_LEN 15 .... char str_name[ MAX_NAME_LEN +1]; ,,, if(  1 != scanf( "%" MAX_NAME_LEN "s", str_name) ) { perror( "scanf failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`   In all cases, the `strlen()` of the name contained in `str_name` cannot be greater than MAX_NAME_LEN, so the code block beginning with `if(strlen...)` will never be executed

Comment: if the two calls to `getchar()` are to get the program to pause so you can read the screen, before it is erased,  They will not have that effect because the 'newline' is still in the input buffer so will be consumed and the program will not pause.  Suggest: `int ch; while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch );  getchar()`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`fgets()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) to read an input buffer.

> `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)` reads a line from the specified stream and stores it in a buffer pointed to by *str*. It stops when either `n-1` characters are read, the newline character is read, or the `EOF` is reached.

Some things to note about `fgets()`:

- Returns `NULL` on error.
- Appends `\n` character at the end of buffer. Can replaced with `\0` instead.
- Buffer must be pointer to an array of characters. Either allocated on the stack or the heap.
- Reads from `stdin` or `FILE` objects.

Here is some example code which shows this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NAMESTRLEN 16

int main(void) {
    char str_name[NAMESTRLEN] = {'\0'};
    size_t slen;

    printf("Please enter your first name to begin: ");
    if (fgets(str_name, NAMESTRLEN, stdin) == NULL) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error from fgets()\n");
        return 1;
    }

    slen = strlen(str_name);
    if (slen > 0 && str_name[slen-1] == '\n') {
        str_name[slen-1] = '\0';
    } else {
        fprintf( stderr, "Too many characters\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (str_name[0] == '\0') {
        fprintf( stderr, "No name entered\n");
        return 1;
    }

    str_name[0] = toupper((unsigned char)str_name[0]);

    printf("Hi %s.\n", str_name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He is not using `scanf`.  He is using `scanf_s` (which already provides protection against buffer overflow).

Comment: It will never detect an overflow. `fgets` will fit the size adding a null terminator at the end of buffer at `size-1`

Comment: @MartinBonner Yes, that is true. You have to agree that `scanf_s()` is not the best way to read strings. What happens if the buffer has spaces?

Comment: "If the buffer has spaces" - hmmmm.  That's an interesting one.  Do we want to allow a single first name with embedded spaces?  It could be someone misread the prompt and typed their full name.  It could be that somebody has a first name with an embedded space. [Names are complicated](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: @MartinBonner Why not be safe then sorry? What happens if the OP decides in the future to also include a last name? I'm sure that would include spaces.

Comment: I'm assuming you downvoted @MartinBonner. If you did, can you tell me what else your not happy with this post?

Comment: I see, but `if (!*str_name)` is non sense and can work only if `char str_name[NAMESTRLEN] = {0};`. It is a local scoped variable and is not zeroed at startup. Moreover OP asks for 15 chars that fit in 16 byte array not into a 15 byte long one.

Comment: @LPs What about checking `if (str_name[0] == '\0')`? Surely thats fine.

Comment: Yes, surely better, but the problem id that array is not zeroed.

Comment: @LPs I guess its safer to zero the array. Changes made :).

Comment: Lastly, with your modifications: `fgets(str_name, NAMESTRLEN+1, stdin)`

Comment: hmmm `NAMESTRLEN` is `16` in this case, I dont think we need the +1 anymore.

Comment: A syou can read on [The Man fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets): _reads in at most one less than size characters_  Which means you must pass 16 to read 15 chars

Comment: error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`, so the `printf()` statements for the error messages should be: `fprintf( stderr, "No name entered\n");`  etc.

Comment: @user3629249 Changed :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code:

- The buffer size is too short: `scanf()` will not read more than 14 bytes into `str_name`, so it is not possible to test if the user entered a name longer than 15 characters.
- `toupper()` should not be given a `char` argument because it is only defined for values of type `unsigned char` and the special value `EOF`. Cast the `char` as `unsigned char`.
- your attempt at pausing before the terminal window closes fails on windows for long names because the extra characters entered by the user are still pending after the `scanf_s()`. `getchar()` reads one and returns immediately, and the program exits and the terminal window closes.  Open the terminal window and run the program manually so it does not close automatically.  With this approach, you can remove the `getchar()` and make the program more portable.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str_name[17];

    printf("Please enter your first name to begin: ");
    if (scanf_s("%16s", str_name, sizeof(str_name))) {
        printf("Premature end of file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (strlen(str_name) > 15) {
        printf("The entered name is too long, please restart the program and try again.");
        return 1;
    }
    str_name[0] = toupper((unsigned char)str_name[0]);
    printf("Hi %s\n", str_name);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is:

```
    char Name[1];  // Declare a single element array.
    Name[0] = toupper(str_name[0]); // Set it to the upper-case first letter.

    // Try and print the nul-terminated string in Name - but there is no
    // trailing zero (and the rest of the name is missing).
    printf("Hi %s.\n", Name);
```

What you need is:

```
    str_name[0] = toupper(str_name[0]);
    printf("Hi %s.\n", str_name);
```

There is another problem that `str_name[0]` is a `char` value, and char may be signed.  If you are using Windows-1252 for example, then `Ä` is 196, or as a signed char, -60.  `toupper` takes an `int`, *which must be positive*¹.  When -60 as a signed char is converted to int, you will get -60, and an out of range error. You need to write this as:

```
    str_name[0] = toupper((unsigned char)str_name[0]);
    printf("Hi %s.\n", str_name);
```

(Sorry.)

¹ [Chrqlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie) points out the requirement is actually that the argument must be one of the values of `unsigned char` (which are - by definition - non-negative) or EOF (which *is* negative)"

Comment: Why Did You Write Sorry ?

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your help! Can you also help me with the first part, where the program tells the user to restart if their entered name is longer than 15?

Comment: @SurajJain : Because this is a horrible complication of the C (and C++) standard which beginners shouldn't have to deal with.  (In fact, it would be nice if seasoned developers didn't have to deal with it either.)  It is a real shame that either `toupper` wasn't defined as taking `char`, or `char` wasn't defined as an unsigned type.

Comment: What's the problem with the first part.  You tell the user to restart the program.  When they do that, they will be prompted again.  (Or did you want the user to be prompted repeatedly?

Comment: While your remark about signed characters addresses a real issue and your proposed fix is correct, note that *toupper takes an int, which must be positive* is incorrect: `toupper` is defined for all values of type `unsigned char` and the special value `EOF` which is specified as having a negative value.

Comment: @chqrlie : Good catch.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str_name[16] = {0};
    size_t len = 0;
    int ch;

    printf("Please enter your first name to begin: ");

    while ((EOF != (ch = fgetc(stdin))) && (ch != '\n') && (len<sizeof(str_name)))
    {
        if (isalpha(ch))
        {
            str_name[len++] = ch;
        }
    }

    if (len==sizeof(str_name))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Name too long\n");
    }
    else
    {
        str_name[len] = '\0';
        printf ("Hi %c%s.\n", toupper(str_name[0]), &str_name[1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I changed the input grabbing function. To check the input str len you should read byte per byte, not a whole string: [fgetc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc) do it. Using scanf with a format specifier like `%14s` it will return you always a trimmed string and you are not able to warn user about a too long Name.

Another point is to check that inserted chars are letters and not other kind of chars: [isalpha](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha) do the job.

Moreover a c-string is composed by chars plus a null terminator ('\0', 0x00 ), so: a 15 chars string wants a 16 bytes array.

Lastly the code you wrote to mahe the first letter uppercase is completely wrong: you are passing to print a 1 char array and not a c string. My solution is one of many.

Comment: Don't do his homework for him. Instead, help him do it himself.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy I'm editing. I'll give him an (I hope) explanation of the posted code.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code and still have the problem where the program exits without displaying "Name too long" message, any ideas?

Comment: @MarkTian What you mean? Look at [this example](http://ideone.com/A7L72q) it works very well. Did you understand that you must input only alpha chars?

Comment: Downvote because why only alpha?  Even in Western European culture the French use names like "Jean-Marie", and as soon as your user is not from Europe, you start needing punctuation fast!

Comment: @MartinBonner OP, if he wants, can add all checks he wants. I really don't jknwo what type of name he want to use. On my italian point of view the code checks are enough. Mainly avoid numbers and other chars.

Comment: I would prefer "no checks".  The chances of your checks rejecting a real user's name are too high (in fact, for a widely deployed app, they approach 100%).

Comment: @MartinBonner Well, opinions: from my point of view it is horrible to allow `123Matk234` as a name.

Comment: If 123Matk234 is the name I prefer to be known by, who are you to say it shouldn't be allowed?  I already gave a more realistic example, and see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_8._Lee (granted, that is a middle name, not a first name, but it *is* her name)